# Compile CoffeeScript files into one js file

Tags: coffeescript, playframework-2.0

I'd like to know if it's possible, using 2.0.2 (or trunk), to compile all my `assets/*.coffee` files into one, defined (say app.js & app.min.js) file, thus **without** using the native compiler ?

Comment: What do you mean by the native compiler, and what do you want to use instead?

Comment: Play framework provide an integrated CoffeeScript compiler, the one I'd like to use, but I don't know if using this one, I can compile all the *.coffee into one. The suggested solution I found was using the native compiler, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I do not also understand what do you mean by "native compiler", but coffee has `-c` parameter to compile and `-j` to join result into one file. Here the way I do it:

`coffee -cj ./js/game.js ./coffee`

Comment: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/AssetsCoffeeScript under Options. I can't be more explicit about the native compiler!

Comment: I don't think its a native compiler (like a coffeescript compiler rewritten in Scala), it just calls out the the coffeescript compiler.

Answer (score 1):

since the only option the scala coffeescript process seems to support at the moment is 'bare'(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/AssetsCoffeeScript#options), you'll probably have to have a process that wraps up your coffeescripts and then places them in the appropriate file. You could use grunt for that task. and the plugin grunt-contrib-coffee to handle the files

```
coffee:
  compile:
    files:
      'app/assets/app.js': [
        'file1.coffee'
        'file2.coffee'
      ]
```

would compile these src files in order and place the compiled file in app/assets/app.js which should get picked up by play.

grunt-contrib-coffee: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just write a build script or use a [cakefile](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html)? Something along the lines of this:

```
fs = require 'fs'
{exec} require 'child_process'

fs.readdir 'path/to/coffee/', (err, files) ->
    concat_result = ''
    concat_file = 'path/to/concat_file.coffee'
    for file in files
        concat_result += fs.readFileSync file, 'utf8'

    concat_file = fs.writeFile concat_file, concat_result
    exec "whatever_compiler -c -o path/to/outfile #{concat_file}", (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        #handle errs
```